# Get all the values from single column in MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have value in `user_id` column (1,47,6). How to get all the values?

I have used following code.

```
$array_data = array($project_id);               
$query = "SELECT * FROM p
    INNER JOIN pl ON p.pl_id = pl.pl_id
    INNER JOIN user ON p.user_id = user.user_id WHERE 
    p.p_id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($array_data);
$result_data = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$ids = array();         
foreach($result_data as $rows) {

    $ids[] = $rows['user_id'];                      

}
$id = implode(',',$ids);
echo $id;
```

This `$id` returns only the first value (1). I need all 3 values. Please help & thanks in advance.

Comment: initialize `$ids = array();` outside the loop, right its getting declared every iteration, here's the idea: initialize outside, push inside the loop, after that then implode outside

Comment: are the tables simply called `p` and `pl`?

Comment: another way is to group concat the ids then `->fetchColumn` it, then explode

Comment: `$id` is getting overwrite all time you should put it out side the loop

Answer (score -1):

Declare the `$ids` array before the loop and echo the imploded content after the array

```
$array_data = array($project_id);               
$query = "select `user_id` from p
          inner join pl on p.pl_id = pl.pl_id
          inner join user on p.user_id = user.user_id where 
          p.p_id=?";


$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($array_data);
$result_data = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

$ids = array();  /* declare variable before loop */

foreach($result_data as $rows) {

    $ids[] = $rows['user_id'];                      

}

$id = implode(',',$ids); /* output after loop */
```

Comment: Implemented as suggest,& added this line after implode statement
echo $id; Still getting one value (1)